# ASP.NET ObjectDataSource UpdateMethod Exception Handling

Tags: asp.net, exception, objectdatasource

I have a GridView control on my page which is connected with ObjectDataSource where TypeName="BLL.MyLogic" DataObjectTypeName="BLL.MyObject" UpdateMethod="MyUpdateMethod".

The update in MyUpdateMethod is conditional which I am checking the conditions before _datacontext.submitchanges(). Depending on my check I throw exceptions like ("not unique") or ("no appropiate logic found") etc. I am catching these exceptions at page level via OnUpdated="MyDataUpdated" of my ObjectDataSource.

These operations just work fine. Problem is after the process is done and even in the case of "exception occured" the GridView gets reloaded and editindex = -1 (initiated). Even if I manually retrieve the editindex and make it editable the form data (data input by user) in the edittemplate gets wipped away. ViewState doesnt work here.

What is the work around to this situation ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the [GridViewUpdatedEventArgs.KeepInEditMode property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewupdatedeventargs.keepineditmode%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to true in your RowUpdated event handler?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
KeepInEditMode is more related to GridView rather to objectdatasource. Challange was not about keeping it on editmode. Challange is to keep it in edit mode along with input data. In other words making it behave like a validation fail. 

In my case, I am keeping it in editmode but because of SelectMethod from objectdatasource is getting invoked right after update, my gridview is getting reloaded and loosing the viewstate data for the input controls inside edit template.

Comment: have you tried putting this in there? I could be wrong, but from what I see in reflector, it looks like having this set to true prevents the gridview from databinding again. You will also probably want to set e.ExceptionHandled to true as well.